# Linux bash sum of two numbers from two commands

Tags: linux, bash

I have two commands which both return numbers.
For example:

```
cat `find -name \*.cd -print` | wc -l

cat `find -name \*.c -print` | wc -l
```

Let's say that the first one returns 10, the other 5.

What would the command which return the sum of them, without changing these commands, look like?

I need something like this:

```
cat `find -name \*.cd -print` | wc -l     +     cat `find -name \*.c -print` | wc -l
```

and it should return 15 in this case.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That command will execute yours two commands and print the sum of the results.

```
echo $(($(cat `find -name \*.cd -print` | wc -l)  + $(cat `find -name \*.c -print` | wc -l)))
```

EDIT:
As @Karoly Horvath commented it would be more readable if it's not a oneliner:

```
cd_count=$(cat `find -name \*.cd -print` | wc -l)
c_count=$(cat `find -name \*.c -print` | wc -l)
echo $(($cd_count + $c_count))
```

Comment: in this case a one-liner is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That's true ;) I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to combine the two searches:

```
cat $(find -regex '.*\.cd?$') | wc -l
```

or

```
find -regex '.*\.cd?$' | xargs cat | wc -l
```

or, if you filenames can contain spaces:

```
find -regex '.*\.cd?$' -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -l
```

Comment: compact and fast one. +1. perhaps it would be better if add a `$` in regex. in case the file name had more periods(.)...

Comment: In this case - good idea to combine the searches. However it doesn't answer the OP's question - "return the sum of them, without changing these commands"

Comment: @damgad: I didn't want to reiterate the other approaches. I posted this as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ expr $(echo 5) + $(echo 10)
15
```

Just replace the echo statements with your commands.